# Transformar tabulações em espaços, é possível?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Tem muita gente que indenta seu código com tabulações ao invés de espaços. Eu não tenho nada contra quem faz isso (só não quero que meus filhos leiam esse tipo de código (brincadeira)), mas quando alguém copia e cola código tabulado em uma pergunta, fica bagunçado. Acho que na hora de exibir, o motor do SE transforma uma tabulação em um espaço.

Existe alguma forma de transformar automaticamente uma tabulação em dois ou quatro espaços nas perguntas? Seria esta uma boa proposta para o meta geral da SE, ou do SOen?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, a recomendação é postar sempre aqui primeiro, e migrar pra lá se for o caso. Isso já foi discutido antes no MSO e MSE, mas nunca foi implementado...

Comment: Algumas discussões no MSE sobre o assunto: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90901/automatically-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-the-original-text, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89730/convert-tabs-to-spaces-actually-status-completed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143632/tabs-converted-to-spaces

Comment: Seria ótimo. Não faz o mínimo sentido preservar como é. Se você posta imagens e deleta, o sistema renumera automaticamente, e tem várias outras coisas "mágicas" do tipo. Não vejo motivo para não ter um simples replace nos tabs no meio dessas coisas automáticas. +1

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo de código bagunçado? Até onde sei, cada tab é convertido em 4 espaços quando renderizada, tanto pelo markdown parser do back-end quanto do preview, como também mencionado por uma das respostas linkadas pelo @bfavaretto acima.

Comment: Acredito que o único problema é quando se mistura tabs com espaços no editor (aí a indentação que parece correta no editor pode renderizar diferente no preview), mas neste caso, na minha opinião, já é culpa do usuário por misturar estilos de indentação e não prestar atenção no preview.

Comment: @Fabrício assim que eu encontrar um exemplo eu posto aqui.